# How to close the "Save" and "Detail" fragments after making changes and return to "Main" fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I want to close the "Save" and "Detail" fragments and return to the "Main" fragment when I press the "save" and "update" buttons, respectively. The problem with my case is that I have to go back manually to see the change, which is not user-friendly. How can I fix that?

[Save Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWSyM.jpg)

[Detail Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFZW8.jpg)

Since, I am using MVVM architecture, I wrote

```
android:onClick="@{() -> saveFragment.save(editTextName.getText().toString())}"
```

and

```
android:onClick="@{() -> detailFragment.update(task.id, editTextName.getText().toString())}"
```

in those fragments, but they only serve for data transfer. How can I combine it with the change in user interface?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), you should call the **popBackStack()** function inside the save and update functions.
Else you should call the supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace() by passing fragmentContainer id and home fragment.